# Tweepy and flask: failed to get request token

Tags: python, flask, tweepy

I tryed to play around with Tweepy and Flask but I get seem to get the request token.

This is the code which fails.

```
CONSUMER_TOKEN='fill this out'
CONSUMER_SECRET='and this'
CALLBACK_URL = 'http://localhost:5000/verify'
session = dict()
db = dict() #you can save these values to a database

@app.route("/")
def send_token():
    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_TOKEN, 
        CONSUMER_SECRET, 
        CALLBACK_URL)

    try: 
        #get the request tokens
        redirect_url= auth.get_authorization_url()
        session['request_token']= (auth.request_token.key,
            auth.request_token.secret)
    except tweepy.TweepError:
        print 'Error! Failed to get request token'

    #this is twitter's url for authentication
    return flask.redirect(redirect_url)
```

It's from [this](https://github.com/whichlight/flask-tweepy-oauth) github project. Of course I replaced the consumer token/secret.

Why does auth.get_authorization_url() fails?

Thank you.

The full log is this

```
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/
Error! Failed to get request token
127.0.0.1 - - [20/Nov/2012 22:54:28] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
127.0.0.1 - - [20/Nov/2012 22:54:29] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

Comment: Can you share more details on the error you are receiving?

Comment: I just get the 'Error! Failed to get request token' in the console and"Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application." in the browser. Then the script seems to be loading the Flask server at localhost:5000 ( according to the terminal ).

Comment: it might be helpful to log the original exception messsage

Answer (score 2):

It looks like Tweepy defaults to using `http://` protocols for the oauth endpoints. You'll need to change your code to force it to use `https://`. This might fix your problem.

You do it when you instantiate the `OAuthHandler` class like this:

```
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_TOKEN, 
    CONSUMER_SECRET, 
    CALLBACK_URL, secure=True)
```

Comment: Thanks but it didn't help. I still get the same "Error! Failed to get request token".